# Get parent record by doing join

Tags: sql, select, join

I want to get title from parent record (first line in a table) and I have only children record (f.x. with categoryid=13, see screen below).

So steps are:
1) get parentid (3) from child record by categoryid (13).
2) by parentid (3) find parent record.
3) get title from parent record.

I have tried such request, but it does not really work as I want:

```
select * from qa_categories as cat
join qa_categories as pcat
ON pcat.categoryid = cat.parentid
where cat.categoryid = "13"
```

[image]

Can somebody help me with what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the right idea, you're just missing the parent's title in the select list:

```
SELECT cat.*, pcat.title AS parent_title
-- Here ------^
FROM   qa_categories AS cat
JOIN   qa_categories AS pcat ON pcat.categoryid = cat.parentid
WHERE  cat.categoryid = "13"
```

Comment: How would I return all fields of parent record: pcat.* does not work?
btw: thanks, it works.

Comment: What happens when you add `pcat.*`? Can you elaborate on "does not work"?

Comment: sorry, I'm an idiot :)
I made mistake in another place and pcat.* did not work and I thought I was doing something illegal.